# How to Change Specific Dictionary Key Value in List of Dicts, and Update CSV entry?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am currently working on an inventory system that takes use of a csv file. My next task is to be able to edit specific entries of specific items.

My CSV file looks like this

[image: CSV File]

Here is my current and relevant code:

```
class CsvReader:
   def __init__(self): 
       self.result = []

   def make_dict_items(self):
       #fn = os.path.join('subdir', "Items2.csv")
       with open("Items2.csv") as fp:
           reader = csv.reader(fp)
           labels = next(reader, None)
           result = []
           for row in reader:
               if row:
                   row[0] = int(row[0])
                   row[1] = float(row[1])
                   row[2] = int(row[2])
                   pairs = zip(labels, row)
                   self.result.append(dict(pairs))

   def return_price(self, item):
       return self.result[item]["Price "]

   def add_item(self):
      item_num = int(input("What is the items #?\n"))
      price = float(input("What is the items price?\n"))
      quant = int(input("What is the items quantity?\n"))
      name = input("What is the items name?\n")
      new_row = [item_num, price, quant, name]
      with open("Items2.csv", "a+") as  fp:
          reader = csv.reader(fp)
          fp.seek(0)
          labels = next(reader, None)
          writer = csv.writer(fp)
          new_record = dict(zip(labels, new_row))
          self.result.append(new_record)
          writer.writerow(new_record.values())


  #method I am messing with/trying to implement
  def change_price(self):
       print(self.result)
       item_to_change = int(input("What item would you like to change the price of?\n"))
       print("The current price of " + return_name(item_to_change) " is " + 
       (return_price(item_to_change))
       price = float(input("What would you like to update the price to?\n"))
       self.result[item_to_change]["Price "] = price
       updated_row = []
       with open("Items2.csv", "a+") as  fp:
          reader = csv.reader(fp)
          fp.seek(0)
          labels = next(reader, None)
          writer = csv.writer(fp)
          new_record
```

I am currently trying to implement a method that can edit the price of specific items in the list of dicts.
For example, if I want to edit Blueberry Muffin, I want to be able to look at the current row of Blueberry Muffin, edit the price of it to some float, and append the specific dict key value, save it to the dict, and implement it in the main csv file and list of dicts.

In lamen terms, I see the Blueberry Muffin is 5.99, and want to be able to change it to 6.99, and implement it to my current csv and display it using the pre-existing methods I have

My last method in my CsvReader class is an attempt to try to implement this. How would I do so? I figure it would be fairly similar to the method I have which adds a new item?

Comment: Is the space in ["Price "] intended?

Comment: @Alceste_ yes, apparently for some reason Price has a space in it, and doesnt work without including that is has a space.

Comment: @Alceste_ added the return price method to the relevant code, didnt realize that method wasnt present

Comment: You cannot insert your modified data in place.  Just open the file for writing, write out the header (which you know), then write out ALL of the records, old modified and new.

Comment: @TimRoberts So I would need to delete the specific row I am trying to change, keep the data I want to keep for the "item", and then insert the new price, and then ultimately add the new row with the new price?

Comment: No, you can modify the dictionary in place.  It's three separate steps.  First, import the CSV into a list-of-dicts.  Now, it's a plain, ordinary Python data structure you can modify to your heart's content.  Finally, you export the list-of-dicts back to a CSV file.

Comment: Hmm, if only Python had an embedded database that would allow you to do what is a bog standard database operation? Save yourself  a lot of work and use [Sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3).